# How to remove element from array if values matched?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

If i find values in object i want to delete those values from array.

What would be the best solution to accompolished this task ?

ctrl.js

```
  var selectedOwners = [];
            $scope.deleteOwner = function(dataItem){
                var workerKey;
                var fullName;
                angular.forEach(selectedOwners,function(val,index){
                  workerKey = val.workerKey;
                  fullName = val.fullName;
                })
                if(dataItem.workeyKey === workerKey || dataItem.fullName === fullName){ 
                  selectedOwners.splice(workerKey,fullName);
                }      
            }
```

Array and Object

```
Array  selectedOwners = [{"fullName":"Johnson, Rocio","workerKey":3506},{"fullName":"Johnson, John S.","workerKey":571},{"fullName":"Johnson, Camille A.","workerKey":1368}]

Object {
    "workerKey": 3506,
    "fullName": "Johnson, Rocio",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as simple as this:

```
var selectedOwners = [{
    "fullName": "Johnson, Rocio",
    "workerKey": 3506
}, {
    "fullName": "Johnson, John S.",
    "workerKey": 571
}, {
    "fullName": "Johnson, Camille A.",
    "workerKey": 1368
}];

var obj = {
    "workerKey": 3506,
    "fullName": "Johnson, Rocio",
};


for (var i = 0; i < selectedOwners.length; i++) {
    if (selectedOwners[i].workerKey === obj.workerKey) {
        selectedOwners.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the for loop assumes that the workerKey is unique in the array. That's is why we only need to compare on the workerKey property only and we also break out of the for loop after find a match.

Here's the loop if the workerKey is not unique:

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectedOwners.length; i++) {
    if (selectedOwners[i].workerKey === obj.workerKey &&
        selectedOwners[i].fullName === obj.fullName) {
        selectedOwners.splice(i, 1);

        // we need to decrement i by one because
        // we just removed an element from the array
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf to get the position for the splice;

Since you're passing the object as dataItem you can do as follow:

```
$scope.deleteOwner = function(dataItem){
    selectedOwners.splice(indexOf(dataItem), 1);
}
```

Comment: its throwing error indexOf is not defined do you think something missing here

Comment: Yes, when you use the function deleteOwner in your ng-repeat, I suppose, you need to pass the element to the function, like:
<div ng-repeat="dataItem in selectedOwners" ng-click="deleteOwner(dataItem)"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash _.remove which is very simple

```
_.remove(selectedOwners , {
          "fullName": "Johnson, Rocio",
          "workerKey": 3506    //where condition
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use grep function, like below:

```
$scope.deleteOwner = function(dataItem){
            selectedOwners = $.grep(selectedOwners, function(value) {
                return value.workerKey != dataItem.workerKey 
                     && value.fullName!= dataItem.fullName;
            });      
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is to use just the filter array's method. No external JS dependencies.

```
var selectedOwners = [{"fullName":"Johnson, Rocio","workerKey":3506},{"fullName":"Johnson, John S.","workerKey":571},{"fullName":"Johnson, Camille A.","workerKey":1368}]
var item = {
    "workerKey": 3506,
    "fullName": "Johnson, Rocio",
}

var resultArray = selectedOwners.filter(function(i){ 
   return !(i.fullname == item.fullname && i.workerKey == item.workerKey)
});
```